# Trying to sum values in a row using VBA and can't solve a bug in code

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA to sum the values across columns in a row. I have found however that when i run the code it receives a type mismatch error on random rows and i cannot figure out why. When i delete all other columns except from the four that are to be added it suddenly does not have this error?

I've also noticed that for some reason it does not add the "serving player backhand" column value as it should and i can't figure out why.

```
Sub sumShotsInRally()

'Set rawData sheet as active
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Sheets("Input")
sht1.Activate

'Find the Columns to Add
Dim serverForehandColNum As Integer
serverForehandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Serving player forehand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

Dim serverBackhandColNum As Integer
serverBackhandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Serving player backhand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

Dim returnerForehandColNum As Integer
returnerForehandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Returning player forehand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

Dim returnerBackhandColNum As Integer
returnerBackhandColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Returning player backhand", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

'Insert two new columns for the x and y
ActiveSheet.Columns(serverForehandColNum + 1).Insert

' Add New col headings
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, serverForehandColNum + 1).Value = "Rally Count"

Dim rallyCountColNum As Integer
rallyCountColNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="Rally Count", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

'Split the cell values
'Define the range to iterate over as the used range of the found column
Dim SForehandRange As Range
Dim SBackhandRange As Range
Dim RForehandRange As Range
Dim RBackhandRange As Range
Dim rallyRange As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set SForehandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, serverForehandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, serverForehandColNum))
    Set SBackhandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, serverBackhandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, serverBackhandColNum))
    Set RForehandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, returnerForehandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, returnerForehandColNum))
    Set RBackhandRange = .Range(.Cells(2, returnerBackhandColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, returnerBackhandColNum))
    Set rallyRange = .Range(.Cells(2, rallyCountColNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rallyCountColNum))
End With

Dim results()
'You redimension the results array to the number of entries in your table
ReDim results(1 To SForehandRange.Rows.Count)
'You loop over your table and sum the values from count and restocked
For i = 1 To SForehandRange.Rows.Count
    rallyRange(i, 1).Value = SForehandRange(i, 1).Value + SBackhandRange(i, 1).Value + RForehandRange(i, 1).Value + RBackhandRange(i, 1).Value
    'results(i) = SForehandRange(i, 1) + SBackhandRange(i, 1) + RForehandRange(i, 1) + RBackhandRange(i, 1)
Next i
'You write the array to the range count and delete the values in restocjed
'rallyRange = Application.Transpose(results)

End Sub
```

A sample of the table:

```
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
|       Name       | Position | Duration | 1st serve outcome | 1stReturnLocation | 1stServeLocation | 1stServeXY | 2nd return outcome | 2nd return stroke | 2nd serve outcome | 2ndReturnXY | 2ndServeLocation | 2ndServeXY |    Date    | Final shot outcome | Game score | Opponent player | Point score  | Point won by |    S/R    | Set score |   Side    | Tagged player | Tiebreak score | Tournament name | 1st return outcome | 1st return stroke | 1stReturnXY | 2nd return+1 outcome | 2nd return+1 position | 2nd return+1 situation | 2nd return+1 stroke | 2nd serve+1 outcome | 2nd serve+1 position | 2nd serve+1 situation | 2nd serve+1 stroke | 2ndReturn+1XY | 2ndReturnLocation | 2ndServe+1XY | Final hit | Final shot position | Final stroke | FinalShotXY | Returning player forehand | Serving player forehand |     Type      | 1st serve+1 outcome | 1st serve+1 position | 1st serve+1 situation | 1st serve+1 stroke | 1stServe+1XY | 1st return+1 outcome | 1st return+1 position | 1st return+1 situation | 1st return+1 stroke | 1stReturn+1XY | Tagged net approach | Returning player backhand | Serving player backhand | Opponent net approach |
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| 0-0 (1)          |   329720 |    23520 | Error             | Error net         | Error net        | 38;52      | Error              | Forehand          | In                | 65;54       | Wide             | 32;38      | 20/08/2011 | Forced error       | 00:00      | Player 2        | 0-0          | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Deuce     | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          |                    |                   |             |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               |                     |                      |                       |                    |              |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 15-0 (1)         |   375000 |     4720 | In                | Error long        | Body             | 60;32      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 | Unforced error     | 00:00      | Player 2        | 15-0         | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Advantage | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | Error              | Backhand          | 65;5        |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               |                     |                      |                       |                    |              |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 30-0 (1)         |   393320 |    17440 | Error             |                   | Error net        | 44;51      | In                 | Forehand          | In                | 57;27       | Body             | 42;34      | 20/08/2011 | Unforced error     | 00:00      | Player 2        | 30-0         | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Deuce     | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          |                    |                   |             | In                   | Middle baseline       | Neutral                | Backhand            | In                  | Middle baseline      | Neutral               | Forehand           | 59;28         | Middle            | 61;27        | Player 1  | Middle baseline     | Forehand     | 39;28       |                         1 |                       1 | Ground stroke |                     |                      |                       |                    |              |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 40-0 (1)         |   428640 |     6360 | In                | Middle            | Wide             | 66;36      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 |                    | 00:00      | Player 2        | 40-0         | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Advantage | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | In                 | Backhand          | 46;20       |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               | Unforced error      | Middle baseline      | Neutral               | Forehand           | 48;29        |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 40-15 (1)        |   450800 |     9840 | In                | Middle            | Wide             | 34;34      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 | Unforced error     | 00:00      | Player 2        | 40-15        | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Deuce     | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | In                 | Forehand          | 55;28       |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              | Player 1  | Middle transition   | Forehand     | 69;50       |                           |                       1 | Approach shot | In                  | Middle baseline      | Neutral               | Forehand           | 57;28        | In                   | Middle baseline       | Neutral                | Backhand            | 69;23         | Yes                 |                           |                         |                       |
| 40-30 (1)        |   485280 |     6680 | In                | Middle            | Body             | 60;33      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 |                    | 00:00      | Player 2        | 40-30        | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Advantage | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | In                 | Backhand          | 59;34       |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               | Unforced error      | Middle inside        | Neutral               | Forehand           | 70;36        |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| SD advantage (1) |   523800 |     4880 | In                | Error long        | Wide             | 64;31      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 | Unforced error     | 00:00      | Player 2        | SD advantage | Player       | Serving   | Set 1     | Advantage | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | Error              | Backhand          | 48;8        |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               |                     |                      |                       |                    |              |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 0-0 (2)          |   577560 |     5520 | In                | Middle            | Wide             | 33;30      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 |                    | 01:00      | Player 2        | 0-0          | Player       | Returning | Set 1     | Deuce     | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | In                 | Forehand          | 59;30       |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              |           |                     |              |             |                           |                         |               | Unforced error      | Middle inside        | Attacking             | Backhand           | 57;37        |                      |                       |                        |                     |               |                     |                           |                         |                       |
| 0-15 (1)         |   609040 |    11800 | In                | Middle            | Body             | 61;30      |                    |                   |                   |             |                  |            | 20/08/2011 | Winner             | 01:00      | Player 2        | 0-15         | Player       | Returning | Set 1     | Advantage | Player 1      | 00:00          | Repton          | In                 | Backhand          | 57;29       |                      |                       |                        |                     |                     |                      |                       |                    |               |                   |              | Player 1  | Middle baseline     | Forehand     | 28;27       |                         1 |                       1 | Ground stroke | In                  | Advantage wide       | Attacking             | Forehand           | 75;37        | In                   | Middle baseline       | Neutral                | Forehand            | 42;27         |                     |                           |                         |                       |
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------------+------------+------------+--------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: You say *Insert two new columns for the x and y* but then you are inserting only one which you will use for the sum of the values of each of the four columns. Could you clarify? I guess it has something to do with *Split the cell values* which you are also not doing.

Comment: Could  you also explain the layout (the order of the columns) e.g. the four columns are `E,F,G,H` and I+m inserting the Rally Count Column before column `E`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 apologies i have been trying different means to fix this and have resorted to an older version of my code and forgot to update the comments again. I am attempting to insert a single new column called Rally Count (this part appears to work fine). I am then trying to add the numbers that exist in four other columns with the titles (serving player forehand, serving player backhand, returning player forehand, returning player backhand). This seems to work in part, for some reason it does not add the serving player backhand column (and there doesn't appear to be any typo's).

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have inserted the Rally Count column after the 'serving player forehand' column. This comes before the returning player columns. I'll try to upload the table to the post.

Comment: I have attempted to upload the table to the post but it is too big apparently, so i can only enter the first few rows.

Comment: I only need to know where the columns are located. It doesn't make sense to me that you would insert the column between columns that are being summed up. So give me an example where the column are located and where you will insert the Rally Count Column. I am interested in the order: e.g. first comes serFore then rallycount then serBack then retFore then retBack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sum Up Cells to Array

- This is how I understand it at the moment. Try it and get back to me in the comments to fix possible issues.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sumShotsInRally()

    'Set rawData sheet as active
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Input")
    
    'Find first column to sum
    Dim sForeCol As Long
    sForeCol = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Serving player forehand", _
                               Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    
    'Add Rally Count Column.
    Dim rallyCountCol As Long
    rallyCountCol = sForeCol + 1
    ws.Columns(rallyCountCol).Insert
    ws.Cells(1, rallyCountCol).Value = "Rally Count"
    
    'Find remaining columns to sum
    Dim sBackCol As Long
    sBackCol = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Serving player backhand", _
                               Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    Dim rForeCol As Long
    rForeCol = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Returning player forehand", _
                               Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    Dim rBackCol As Long
    rBackCol = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Returning player backhand", _
                               Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    
    'Define the range to iterate over as the used range of the found column
    Dim sFore As Range
    Dim sBack As Range
    Dim rFore As Range
    Dim rBack As Range
    Dim RallyCount As Range
    
    'Define column ranges
    With ws
        Set sFore = .Range(.Cells(2, sForeCol), _
                           .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, sForeCol))
        Set sBack = .Range(.Cells(2, sBackCol), _
                           .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, sBackCol))
        Set rFore = .Range(.Cells(2, rForeCol), _
                           .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rForeCol))
        Set rBack = .Range(.Cells(2, rBackCol), _
                           .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rBackCol))
        Set RallyCount = .Range(.Cells(2, rallyCountCol), _
                                .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, rallyCountCol))
    End With
    
    'Define Results Array
    Dim Results As Variant
    'You redimension the results array to the number of entries in your table
    ReDim Results(1 To sFore.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    'You loop over your table and sum the values from count and restocked
    For i = 1 To sFore.Rows.Count
        Results(i, 1) = sFore(i, 1) + sBack(i, 1) + rFore(i, 1) + rBack(i, 1)
    Next i
    'You write the array to the range count and delete the values in restocjed
    RallyCount.Value = Results

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to look at this, much appreciated. It seems to throw an error on the line: Results(i) = sFore(i, 1) + sBack(i, 1) + rFore(i, 1) + rBack(i, 1) Error: Subscript Out of Range

Comment: @VBasic2018 i'm wondering is it because the initial cells in the columns are blank and so the range it creates for each of the columns SFore, SBack, RFore and RBack will actually be 0 or 1? A lot of the cells are blank as there is no rally.

Comment: @user3112721: No, no, no. My mistake. The line should be `Results(i, 1)...` because it's a 2D one-column array. Will change code immediately.

Comment: @VBasic2018 you're a legend that worked a treat. Thanks very much again for you help greatly appreciated. Now onto my next issue :-) Thanks again